# Prove the Martingale Property for a sequence of Random Variables

Tags: probability, martingales, expected-value

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}(0,1)$, P=Lebesgue measure and $X_{n}$ is a random variable defined as
$X_n(w)=
\begin{cases}
0 \quad \frac{1}{n} < w \leq 1 \\
n-n^2w \quad 0 \leq w \leq \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$

and $F_n=\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ is the sigma algebra generated by $X_{1},...,X_{n}$

I want to prove that $X_n$ is a martingale, I succeeded in proving the first 2 statements of the definition but I've problems with the Martingale property $E(X_{n+1}|F_{n})=X_n$.

Comment: I don't think that it is a martingale but perhaps I'm missing something. As $X_1(\omega)=1-\omega$ it holds that $\sigma(X_1) = \sigma(\text{id})$ and the latter equals $\mathcal{F}$; this however, would imply $\mathcal{F}_n = \mathcal{F}$ for all $n$ and so there is no way that $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_n$ is a martingale.

Answer (score 0):

$(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not a Martingale:

Let $n\geq1$. Then $X_n^{-1}((n-n^2\frac{1}{n+1},\infty))=[0,\frac{1}{n+1})\in\sigma(X_n)$.
Now we compute 
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n+1})}(X_{n+1}-X_n)\right)&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{n+1}}n+1-(n+1)^2t-(n-n^2t)\text{ dt}\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{n+1}}1-(2n+1)t\text{ dt}\\
&=\left[t-\frac{2n+1}{2}t^2 \right]_0^\frac{1}{n+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{2n+1}{2(n+1)^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}\\
&\neq 0
\end{align*}